# how to solve ports dependencies conflict

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

What is the best approach to avoid conflict among the dependencies from two or more unrelated ports? I'm facing the following problem. A script that I'm using has the follow approach to try to install all dependencies of a port:

assuming $PORTA is pointing for a specific port (/usr/ports/lang/php5 for example)

```
# Complete dependency chain first
BUILDLIST=`cd $PORTA && make build-depends-list 2>/dev/null`
for BUILD in $BUILDLIST; do
    # Check to see if item is already built
local _PKGNAME=`make -C $PORTA -V PKGNAME`
if [ `grep -c "$_PKGNAME" /tmp/pfPort_alreadybuilt` -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "    Dependency $BUILD of $PORTA already built on this run.  Skipping."
else
   echo "    Building dependency $BUILD of $PORTA"
   clean_build_install_clean $BUILD
fi
done
```

After it tried to install the whole dependencies, then it will try to install the port.

Is it any better than go through your ports and do a `make depends install clean`? With the approach listed, I'm having a lot of trouble with minor versions conflicts like perl 5.12.4 is needed, but Perl.14.2 is installed and I have the feeling that make depends make handle it better.

Comment: Did `make depends install` handle it better?

Comment: FreeBSD ports already will already install all their dependencies before installing themselves. So why are you doing this?